SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - without .copy()
My features is a series and if I do not use the features.copy, I receive the warning:
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
But use a copy here seems to be more slow and uses more memory allocation too.
I receive the values from a function and return a dict:
def get_variables(features: pd.DataFrame, hs: float, qv: float, level: float) -> dict:

    features = features.copy()
    features['level_sqrt'] = np.sqrt(level)
    features['spread'] = hs
    features['spread_sqrt'] = np.sqrt(hs)
    features['queue_volume_sqrt'] = np.sqrt(qv)
    features['queue_volume'] = qv

What can be the best approach to get the best performance and uses of memory?
I am trying to get a better solution that do not use the features.copy() and have a better performance and use of memory.

Please provide a [MRE].

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/4601890 helps?
